# Problem while installing steam : libglapi-mesa:i386

Tags: package-management, steam

It seem to be a common issue but I have done many research on forum and still didn't manage to find out how to resolve this issue, when trying to install steam I get this :

```
Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Dépend: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 20.0.4-2ubuntu1) but will not be installed
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Dépend: libgl1:i386 but will not be installed
                        Dépend: libglx-mesa0:i386 but will not be installed
```

Sorry for the mixed french/english

I have a nvidia card ( don't know if it can help ? )

Thx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Answer (score 1):

The `focal-updates` which provide the required dependencies is missing in your sources. Edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` as follow:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```

then run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
```